# RedirectView from Spring MVC dont works

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

I think the fault comes from ulr introduced in the `RedirectView` parameter, but I tried different URL's and I can't make it work.

This is my project estructure:

[image: Project Structure]

And this is the get method from Spring MVC in controller package

```
@GetMapping("/planetForm")
@ResponseBody
public RedirectView toPlanetForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "idPlanet", required = false) String idPlanet) {
    if (idPlanet != null){
        Planet planet = planetService.getById(Integer.parseInt(idPlanet));
        model.addAttribute("planet", planet);
    }
    List<Satellite> satellites = satelliteService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("satellites", satellites);
    return new RedirectView("./addPlanet");
}
```

As you can see I am trying to do the RedirectView to the JSP called addPlanet.jsp.
I have also tried this url (among others): `"../webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/addPlanet.jsp"`, I am convinced that it is a rookie nonsense, but I am unable to see the error

I have also tried to create another servlet and retrieve the object I need through the `@ModelAtribute`, but the object added in the first servlet is lost in the process, this is the code:

```
@GetMapping("/updatePlanet")
@ResponseBody
String update(Model model, @ModelAttribute("planet") Planet planet){
    model.addAttribute("planet",planet);
    return "addPlanet";
}
```

This wat sends the user to the `addPlanet.jstl`, but the object obtained by this method is an object just created by the constructor with attributes with the value of null or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, here it is:

```
@GetMapping("/planetForm/{idPlanet}")
public String toPlanetForm(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "idPlanet", required = false) String idPlanet) {
    if (idPlanet != null){
        Planet planet = planetService.getById(Integer.parseInt(idPlanet));
        model.addAttribute("planet", planet);
    }
    List<Satellite> satellites = satelliteService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("satellites", satellites);
    return "addPlanet";
}
```

As you can see I had to change the `@GetMapping` for a new URL, now the function returns a String which is the name of the JSP without extension. In addition to the parameter of the function `@RequestParam` I have had to change it to`@PathVariable`, which its value is the same as the mustache expression of `@GetMapping`